# What to set in steps_per_epoch in Keras' fit_generator?

Tags: keras, epochs

I am replicating, in Keras, the work of a paper where I know the values of `epoch` and `batch_size`. Since the dataset is quite large, I am using `fit_generator`. I would like to know what to set in `steps_per_epoch` given `epoch` value and `batch_size`. Is there a standard way?

Answer (score 32):

As mentioned in Keras' [webpage](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#fit_generator) about `fit_generator()`:

> ***steps_per_epoch***: Integer. Total number of steps (batches of samples)
> to yield from generator **before declaring one epoch finished** and
> starting the next epoch. It should typically be equal to
> **ceil(num_samples / batch_size)**. Optional for Sequence: if unspecified,
> will use the len(generator) as a number of steps.

You can set it equal to `num_samples // batch_size`, which is a typical choice.

However, `steps_per_epoch` give you the chance to "trick" the generator when updating the learning rate using `ReduceLROnPlateau()` [callback](https://keras.io/callbacks/#reducelronplateau), because this callback checks the drop of the loss once each epoch has finished. If the loss has stagnated for a `patience` number of consecutive epochs, the callback decreases the learning rate to "slow-cook" the network. If your dataset is huge, as it is usually the case when you need to use generators, you would probably like to decay the learning rate within a single epoch (since it includes a big number of data). This can be achieved by setting `steps_per_epoch` to a value that is **less than** `num_samples // batch_size` without affecting the overall number of training epochs of your model.

Imagine this case as using mini-epochs within your normal epochs to change the learning rate because your loss has stagnated. I have found it very useful [in my applications](https://github.com/pcko1/Deep-Drug-Coder/blob/master/ddc_pub/ddc_v3.py#L1008-L1011).

Comment: I saw the documentation before posting the question, I couldn't understand what it means by `num_samples`. Does it mean total number of rows in `x_train` file?

Comment: The learning rate is decayed at each step, not at each epoch, according to https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/7a39b6c62d43c25472b2c2476bd2a8983ae4f682/keras/optimizers.py#L197

Comment: @Bananach I believe we are saying the same thing, right?

Comment: I didn't think so. You are `saying steps_per_epoch` allows for the learning rate to be adjusted *during*  a pass through the samples, by `setting steps_per_epoch < num_samples//batch_size`. I am saying that that'll happen anyway even with `steps_per_epoch=num_samples//batch_size`, and it'll happen exactly `steps_per_epoch` often

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Do you have any references which show when `get_updates` is called? It would be interesting to see

Comment: @pcko1: What does it mean then, if `steps_per_epoch` is **larger** than `num_samples // batch_size`? Because I saw few cases like that.

Comment: The real question is : after steps_per_epoch batches have passed and the epoch is considered finished, will the next epoch start again from 1st batch of the dataset or will it continue from the next batch ? If it starts again at first batch, this is an issue as some batches in the dataset will never be used.

Answer (score 6):

I think it would be nice to have the following relation hold

```
steps_per_epoch * batch_size = number_of_rows_in_train_data
```

This will result in usage of all the train data for one epoch.
Also, consider using `fit()` instead of `fit_generator()` if you need to have fast performance, but take into account that `fit()` might use more memory.

Comment: I think that relation does hold. At least, that's implied here: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/12/24/how-to-use-keras-fit-and-fit_generator-a-hands-on-tutorial/

Comment: @StatsSorceress: This is only true when the number_of_rows_in_train_data is divisible by batch_size. Otherwise, I assume, the remaining data is unused.

Answer (score 5):

For example, if you have 100 training samples, then `num_samples` = 100, or the number of rows of `x_train` is 100.

You can specify your own batch size. In this case, say `batch_size` = 20. As a result, you can set your `steps_per_epoch` = 100/20 = 5 because in this way you can make use of the complete training data for each epoch.

If you also want to ask the scenario you want to set `steps_per_epoch` != `num_samples`/`batch_size` (for example, when `num_samples` cannot be fully divided by `batch_size`), please refer to this post: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/10164

Answer (score 3):

**Let's clear it :**

Assume you have a dataset with **8000 samples (rows of data)** and you choose a `batch_size = 32` and `epochs = 25`

This means that the dataset will be divided into (8000/32) = **250 batches**, having **32 samples/rows in each batch.** The model weights will be updated after each batch.

one epoch will train 250 batches or 250 updations to the model.

here `steps_per_epoch` = no.of batches

With 50 epochs, the model will pass through the whole dataset 50 times.

Ref - https://machinelearningmastery.com/difference-between-a-batch-and-an-epoch/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the formal definition : It should typically be equal to the number of unique samples of your dataset divided by the batch size.

This is how it works,

When you provide **'s'** steps per epoch ,
Each **'s'** step will have **'x'** batches each consisting **'n'** samples are sent to fit_generator,

So, if you specify *5* steps per epoch, each epoch computes **'x'** batches each consisting of **'n'** samples 5 times, then the next epoch is started!